# nohup bash call with sleep is evaluated incorrectly

Tags: bash, nohup

I am trying do execute a script, detached, with a delay and in the background.

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "[$(date)][${HOST}] Immediate date" > ~/out.log
nohup bash -c "sleep 2 && echo '[$(date)][${HOST}] Delayed date'" >> ~/out.log 2>&1 &
```

I expect that out.log would contain exactly two lines like so:

```
[Tue Apr  4 08:55:56 CEST 2017][] Immediate date
[Tue Apr  4 08:55:58 CEST 2017][] Delayed date
```

Note the timestamps being 2 seconds apart. But instead bot dates read exactly the same time...

```
[Tue Apr  4 08:55:56 CEST 2017][] Immediate date
[Tue Apr  4 08:55:56 CEST 2017][] Delayed date
```

When I try it without the `nohup` and `bash -c` the output is as expected, but the calling script would have to keep running, otherwise the second command will be aborted.

What causes the date not being different and to fix it?

**edit:**

I had simplified the command for stackoverflow. But now when I expand it again I run into another variable expansion problem. When I add the `HOST` variable:

```
HOST=foo.bar
nohup bash -c 'sleep 2 && echo "[$(date)][${HOST}]" Delayed date' >> ~/out.log 2>&1 &
```

the output file dos not contain `foo.bar`:

```
[Tue Apr  4 12:52:11 CEST 2017][]
```

Comment: Is it wrong if include `sleep 2` just between the first `echo` and the `nohup` command? wouldn't that solve your purpose?

Comment: That wouldn't work. It would cause the calling program to wait 2 seconds. Instead I want the calling program to continue and only the command executed later (1 minute or so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(date)` is evaluated by the outside shell script. If you swap the `"` with the `'`, it works as you expect it to work. This is because `$(..)` in double quotes is resolved, even if you put it in single quotes inside the double quoted string.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "[$(date)][${HOST}] Immediate date" > ~/out.log
nohup bash -c 'sleep 2 && echo "[$(date)]['"${HOST}"'] Delayed date"' >> ~/out.log 2>&1 &
```

Edit: Make the code work w.r.t. `$HOST` + $HOST containing whitespace

Comment: Good point, but suggesting to make the expansion local to just `nohup bash -c 'sleep 2 && echo ["$(date)"]["${HOST}"] Delayed date'`

Comment: This answer solves half the problems: The date is correct, but now `${HOST}` remains unresolved

Comment: @HarmDoedens Adressed by edit. "Interrupt" the singly-quoted string around the ${HOST} variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that double quotes in the nohup will evaluate the expression in the nohup command immediately.
Changing your double quotes into single quotes (and using the double quotes for the echo may help, e.g

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "[$(date)][${HOST}] Immediate date" > ~/out.log
nohup bash -c 'sleep 2 && echo "[$(date)][${HOST}] Delayed date"' >> ~/out.log 2>&1 &
```